# Segfault when searching through linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
newnode = head;
tempnode = head;
if (head)
{
    while (tempnode)
    {
        if (tempnode->next != NULL)
        {
            cout << tempnode->labValue << " ";
            tempnode = tempnode->next;
        }
    }
}
```

So I have this code that searches through a linked list I made and prints the value of it. It succeeds in printing each value, but then it goes into a sig fault. I have looked all over and each time I try something I still get the sig fault. I'm assuming I get the error because I'm trying to access memory that is not there, so I tried checking by using the while loop and if statement but still no luck. I am sorry if this is a common question, I am frustrated.

Comment: I don't see a segfault, but when `tempnode->next == NULL` you do not advance `tempnode` and will never exit the loop.

Comment: Have you tried using `valgrind` or a debugger?  Based on what you've posted, my guess is you forgot to set the final node's `next` to `NULL`.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: I think you need to give more information. You've shown us where your issue exhibits itself, but not the code where it is caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of the linked list is probably not null terminated. If you don't explicitly set the tail node's next pointer to null, the next pointer could point to garbage (e.g. uninitialized data). The pointer value won't be null, which is why you'll enter the loop and crash.

Put a breakpoint at the while loop and verify this.

By the way, it's useful to use `nullptr` for null pointer values. You'll also need to break out of the while loop for the case when `tempnode->next == NULL`, since tempnode won't be null at that point.

Comment: Ah thank you so much! I wasn't aware I had to set the node next to tail pointer to nullptr.